# Win8 many apps crashing at startup

Tags: windows-8, crash

I was using AVG free for a while without problems. I finally decided to update to the latest AVG Free edition, but suddenly many (I mean really lots of apps, 10+) fail or crash at win8 startup and they seem to be random after later restarts, just after logging in. Several alert windows appear showing the message "X program has stopped working".

I tried restoring to a past windows point (dated 1 month before the update) and had no success. I also uninstalled avg and still no success.

However, when I log through win safe mode with networking, is flawless (excepting the obvious lack of sound, and some drivers, etc), but it does not show even a single alert.

I'm completely lost, what can I do?

Please take into account that I'm not very familiar with windows 8.

Comment: What exactly is "win secure mode"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant windows safe mode with networking, I have win8 in spanish and didn't know the exact name

Comment: If you boot just without AVG do these applications work?

Comment: Nope, I uninstalled it and these alerts remain

Comment: If it works in Safe Mode it should work in a minimal boot configuration.  You replied within 2 minutes, I have my doubts, you actually tried my suggestion

Comment: It happened a week ago and I tried that, and since I couldnt fix it on my own, I'm asking here. And I'm writing this in another laptop, also thanks for replying

Comment: Do you understand what i mean by minimal boot configuration?

Comment: No, I thought you mean safe mode, how can I do that minimal boot conf?

Comment: Using a program called, Autoruns, a tool written by Microsoft is one way

Comment: @Ramhound, I set everything on startup to disabled, and only three alerts appear: "Windows update stopped working", "host process for windows tasks" and "efs ui application has stopped working". After logging in only these three messages appear and nothing can be done, just a black screen

Comment: If I press ctrl+alt+del the red menu containing block, switch user, logout change pass and task manager options appears. However they don't work.

Comment: A minimal configuration is enough to to get Windows to function normally but nothing else.  Its system specific.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to proceed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37874/discussion-between-cyberdelphos-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled AVG again and it worked perfectly on safe mode, also found 440 threats and removed them. I think that was the problem.

Then after trial and error, I found 3 suspicious entries using [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)  (suggested by @Ramhound), which I disabled, and everything started working again.

The suspicious entries included special characters like `{` and `%` and some apparently random characters.

Hope it helps someone to solve this problem.